# Make a table with a MySQL query with multiple values in some fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'v got a probled with a MySQL query or my logic.

I need to make a html table with values from my DATABASE. But in some fields of my table can be a multiple value. How should I make my table? Can I do it in one query or should I do a 2nd query after the table is finished?

Here are the tables:

```
offers:
id   |   rid   |    name 
------------------------------
1    |  1234   |    mary
2    |  1235   |    john
3    |  5342   |    liam

geo_in_off:
offer_id   |   geo_id   
------------------------------
1       |  1  
1       |  2   
3       |  3
```

Some offers can Have 2 geo's. So I need a htm ltable that should looks like:

```
No  |  rid  | name  | geo
----------------------------------
1   | 1234  | mary  | 1, 2
```

But i get a table with dublicates looking like:

```
No  |  rid  | name  | geo
----------------------------------
1   | 1234  | mary  | 1  
2   | 1234  | mary  | 2
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
require('../config.php');
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `offers` LEFT JOIN `geo_in_off` ON `geo_in_off`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id` ORDER BY `offers`.`rid`";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td class=\"editable\">" . $row['rid'] . "</td><td class=\"editable\">" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" .$row['geo_id'] . "</td></tr>"  ;
$i++;
}
```

here is the config.php:

```
$db_name = "dbname";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$db_connect = mysql_connect('localhost', $db_user, $db_pass);
$selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connect);
@mysql_query('set character_set_results="utf8"');
@mysql_query('set collation_connection="utf8_general_ci"');
@mysql_query('set character_set_client="utf8"');
```

Comment: You need to implement what’s known as a _control break_. Basically you compare the relevant field of the current record with that of the last one, and based on whether they are the same or not, you decide what to do. Or you could put the data into an array first, where you can arrange it as you like, using the rid as key, and then you loop over that array to output your desired HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** use `group_concat` and `group by` clause

`GROUP_CONCAT()` will returns a string with concatenated `non-NULL` value from a `group`

```
SELECT  offers.rid,offers.name,group_concat(geo_in_off.geo_id) 
FROM `offers` 
LEFT JOIN `geo_in_off` 
ON `geo_in_off`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id` 
GROUP BY `offers`.`rid`,offers.name  
ORDER BY `offers`.`rid`
```

**Note :**  `GROUP_CONCAT` functions Default separator of is `comma(,)` . also able to use `custom` one .

**2nd :** `mysql_*` is `deprecated` try to use `mysqli_*`

**3rd :** Also try to use `pdo or prepared statement`

**PHP :**

```
require('../config.php');


$sql ="SELECT  `offers`.`rid` as Rid ,`offers`.`name` as Name ,group_concat(geo_in_off.geo) as geos 
        FROM `offers` 
        LEFT JOIN `geo_in_off` 
        ON `geo_in_off`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id` 
        GROUP BY `offers`.`rid`,`offers`.`name`  
        ORDER BY `offers`.`rid`";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $get_result =$stmt->get_result();
 $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

 if($row_count>0){  

    echo "<table><thead><tr><th>No</th><th>Rid</th><th>name</th><th>goes</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    $i=0;
    while ($row=$get_result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td class=\"editable\">" . $row['Rid'] . "</td><td class=\"editable\">" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" .$row['geos'] . "</td></tr>";
        $i++;

    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";

 }
```

**Config.php**

```
$db_name = "dbname";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $db_user, $db_pass,$db_name) or die('error'.mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_query($conn,'set character_set_results="utf8"');
mysqli_query($conn,'set collation_connection="utf8_general_ci"');
mysqli_query($conn,'set character_set_client="utf8"');
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch my master! But could you tell me, how to get the geos in the HTML TABLE now? (the php code)

Comment: @Downvoter can you please explain why it's deserved downvote .so that i can correct my mistake .

Comment: You can not select columns that are not part of the grouping, that is an error in SQL. In MySQL it is treated as an error in strict configuration, and otherwise you get values for a “random” record in the group for these columns.

Comment: thank you very much. But I got an error - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object . Shoud I use some other code in config.php ?

Comment: thank you - buit got again a error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-objec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150283/discussion-between-jyothi-and-mrdeath4).

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use a Separate Table For storing values of "geo". Multi Valued attribute results in data redundancy in the database as well as it is against the Database Normal Form .

i.e

```
 No  |  rid  | name  | 
----------------------------------
 1   | 1234  | mary  |   
 2   | 1234  | mary  | 

 No  |  geo  | foreigh_key  |
----------------------------------
  1   | 1  |  1 |   
  2   | 2  | 1  |
```

Comment: I think they already have that, the question is merely about outputting the data in the desired format.